# Script to scroll Google Sheet works, until I activate another cell. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where the top 3 rows, including column headers, are frozen. When user data is entered in cell A1, my script copies it to a cell in a different row of the spreadsheet, and activates that cell so it will be visible to the user, even if that row had been scrolled out of view. All that works properly, until I add the next line of code -to reactivate cell A1 for the next user input.

Here's the sample script I am using to troubleshoot the problem. I am very new to Google Apps Script. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
    // Practice script: scroll to show 
    // a cell where new data was just added

    var range = e.range;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
    var cellAddress = e.range.getA1Notation(); 
    var inputCell = 'A1';
    var inputData = sheet.getRange(inputCell).getValue(); // get user input       

     // If edited cell was A1, scroll to cell (5,5) and record user input     
     if (cellAddress === inputCell) {
     sheet.getRange(5,5).activate(); 
     sheet.getRange(5,5).setValue(inputData);

     // then reactivate inputCell

     // If the following line is executed, the sheet won't scroll to (5,5) 
     // sheet.getRange(1,1).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` between your `.activate()` lines.

Comment: Ross -that helped. It made the scroll work, but now the last line doesn't activate (1,1).

Comment: Try to add another one at the end of your code.

Comment: That brought back the problem I started with, it doesn't scroll, but does activate the inputCell (1,1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly,  upon editing A1 you want to:

scroll to a cell (5,5), wait, then scroll back to A1

If so, add a delay using Utilities.sleep(3000) - this will wait 3 seconds:

```
//If the following line is executed, the sheet won't scroll to (5,5) 
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
Utilities.sleep(3000)
sheet.getRange(1,1).activate();
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think I needed a pause, but it fixed the problem. I decreased the wait time to 50 and don't think my users will notice the pause. I'd really like to understand why it didn't work before. Do you know?

Comment: I think it did work, looking at the execution time it took 0 seconds so it happened so quickly it wasn't noticeable without the pause.

Comment: If it had worked with my original code, activating cell (5,5) would have made that cell scroll up and be visible to the users. Then, activating (1,1) in the frozen rows of the headers, would have had no effect on rows below the headers. Cell (5,5) would have remained visible. Instead, it stayed off the bottom of the screen. Adding the delay definitely made a difference. Thanks again!

Comment: Worked for me without any `sleep`. I just activated the cell for scroll, `flush()`ed it and then activated my input cell back. Worked like charm!